# How do I configure Cloudfoundry to publish multiple websites internally? Lattice?

Tags: cloud-foundry

My goal is to download static websites with its resources. Put them into separate Docker containers and push them to my private Cloudfoundry. I want the Websites and their resources to have the same domain and path as the original website (only available in the internal network).

The system will be a test environment for a crawler running on a hadoop cluster. Is Cloudfoundry ([v220](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-release/releases/tag/v220)) enough or do I need [Lattice](http://lattice.cf/) and [Diego](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/diego-release)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need CloudFoundry and diego (required for running dockerized workload). For CF v220 you will need diego version 0.1434. I don't think lattice supports creating domains yet.

You will need to do following in order to achieve this:

1. Create domains in CF corresponding to the website domains you want to host.
2. Map these domains to app that you will `push`. Make sure that backend for these apps is diego as it supports dockerized workloads. You can find out more details on how to specify the backend for your app from diego documentation (refer to diego's github page)
3. In your internal network, make sure that dns resolution will resolve these domains to loadbalancer in CF (haproxy that comes with CF or any other LB that you use to load balance requests to CF).

Answer (score 0):

Diego, Docker and Lattice have very little to do with what you're trying to do. The [static file buildpack](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/staticfile/index.html) is a much easier way of generating a lot of apps with static content than building docker containers for each app.

Comment: Because I want the websites and their resources to have the same domain and paths as the original website I might run into problems with different operating systems on the webservers. Therefore I need a mapping of the original path/file (example: "/strange%*/.file?.h.htm") to the local copy of the file (example: "6qpwg4t7mxyn2kah92c7"). How would I achieve this?